# Remove useless zero from scientific notation in PHP

Tags: php

Is there any way to Remove useless zero from scientific notation and make the number as simple as possible.

In PHP I have the following code:

```
<?PHP
  $result = 1/1000000000;
  echo $result;
?>
```

the output is **1.0E-9**

it should **1E-9**

Comment: try this (1/1000000000) in your browser console log
its show you 1e-9

I want to same result but in php

Answer (score 0):

If you need it this way you can use [str_replace](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$result = 1/1000000000;
echo str_replace(".0E", "E", $result);
```

This outputs `1E-9`